# list including another list xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

i have problem to implement list inside another list , i have list of items every item have list of sizes, quantity and price. User choose size and enter quantity then choose parent item, how can implement that in xamarin forms?

[image: example from our data]

Comment: nested lists are generally a bad idea.  Consider using a grouped ListView or CollectionView instead

Comment: As @Jason said above, doing lists inside lists is very bad idea. Their scroll will get conflicted and will end up in poor user experience and performance. Use a grouped listview or worst case use a bindable stacklayout inside a list item to show more of a list which will have a limited items

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Bindable Layout with a nested CollectionView or ListView, this would allow you to use a List of Lists for your data bindings.

it could look something like this;

C#

```
public class MyNestedListItem {
    
    public MyNestedListItem(string myTest)  {
        MyText = myText;
    }

    public string MyText { get; set; }
}


public class MyList {

    public MyList(string listName, list<MyNestedListItem> myNestedList) {
        ListName = listName;
        MyNestedList = myNestedList; 
    }
    
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public List<MyNestedListItem> MyNestedList { get; set; }
}


public class MyViewModel {
    
    public ObservableCollection<MyList> MyList { get; set }

    public MyViewModel() {

        var nestedListA = new List<MyNestedListItem> 
        { 
            new MyNestedListItem("A1"); 
            new MyNestedListItem("A2"); 
            new MyNestedListItem("A3"); 
        }

        var nestedListB = new ...;


        MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyList> {
            new MyList("List A", nestedListA);
            new MyList("List B", nestedListB);
        } 
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Frame WidthRequest="75" 
            HeightRequest="25"
            CornerRadius="25"
            Padding="0"
            HasShadow="True">
        <Label Text="{Binding ListName }"
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyNestedList }" 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                    < ..... your layout stuff here />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

This could be a good starting point to achieve a nested list

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-row and four-column **Grid** inside the listview to avoid nested lists.

It can be easier to implement your page style.

Check this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) for more information.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="myList" RowHeight="150">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                        <Label 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="product name" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="product num"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="product price"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="product count"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                        <Label 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding name}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding count}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding pri}"/>
                        <Entry Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"></Entry>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]